# Get the created date for an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been accessing the AWS API using the Ruby SDK.

I have been trying to find how I can get the created date of an S3 bucket. When I'm viewing the bucket via the console, I can see the bucket printed there in text but I can't seem to find any way of accessing it via the API.

I tried numerous different ways, and dumped my data with YAML to a text file to see other data but there's nothing there that helps.

I was expecting the simple:

```
s3.buckets do |bucket| 
  bucket.creation_date 
end
```

to work, but the method does not exist. Is there another way of accessing the created date value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question with using the Client module for S3: `s3.client.list_buckets()`
Returns:
`{:name=>"bucket", creation_date=>"2013-11-27T06:09:15.000Z"}`

I find it annoying that the created_date isn't very well documented in their API. As with EC2, you can ask for a collection of instances, then query them for their launch_time. I was expecting S3 to be somewhat similar.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using AWS ruby SDK. I never tried that. However, I can achieve the same in [AWS ruby Core SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/V20060301.html#list_buckets-instance_method):

The code:

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'

Aws.config = {
  :access_key_id => "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY",
  :secret_access_key => "YOUR_SECRET_KEY",
  :region => 'YOUR_REGION'
}

s3 = Aws::S3.new
s3.list_buckets.each do |resp|
  resp.buckets.each do |bucket|
    puts "#{bucket.name} ----> #{bucket.creation_date}"
  end
end
```

and the output:

```
MyBucket1 ----> 2014-01-22 16:25:18 UTC
MyBucket2 ----> 2014-01-31 10:18:58 UTC
MyBucket3 ----> 2014-02-24 12:20:17 UTC
MyBucket4 ----> 2014-01-28 14:16:26 UTC
MyBucket5 ----> 2014-01-30 06:42:39 UTC
```

I have omitted my actual bucket names for obvious reason.

Comment: The core-sdk works pretty well, but trying to avoid using 2 different sdk's for one program at the moment. I found a solution - will be posting it soon.

Answer (score -1):

Just check the doc of the aws-ruby sdk. I need to make sure that the particular method is present of not.

Comment: I've already done that, I wouldn't have asked on here if I hadn't checked the API beforehand.